# SwiftUI - How to disable sidebar from collapsing?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

[Gif to understand easier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihlrz.jpg)

Is there any way to disable collapsibility of SidebarListStyle NavigationViews?

Comment: Found a solution?

Comment: @DiogoAntunes nope. Best thing to do is to just add a toggle button so the user doesn't get lost, at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: This method still works as of late 2022, and has never stopped working on any version of macOS (up to latest Ventura 13.1). Not sure why there are answers here suggesting otherwise. If the Introspection library changes their API you may need to update your calls accordingly, but the gist of the solution is the same.

---

Using this SwiftUI Introspection library:
https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

We can introspect the underlying `NSSplitView` by extending their functionality:

```
public func introspectSplitView(customize: @escaping (NSSplitView) -> ()) -> some View {
    return introspect(selector: TargetViewSelector.ancestorOrSibling, customize: customize)
}
```

And then create a generic extension on `View`:

```
public extension View {
    func preventSidebarCollapse() -> some View {
        return introspectSplitView { splitView in
            (splitView.delegate as? NSSplitViewController)?.splitViewItems.first?.canCollapse = false
        }
    }
}
```

Which can be used on our sidebar:

```
var body: some View {
    (...)
    MySidebar()
        .preventSidebarCollapse()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The introspection library mentioned by Oskar is not working for MacOS.

Inspired by that, I figured out a solution for MacOS.

The rationality behind the solution is to use a subtle way to find out the parent view of a `NavigationView` which is a `NSSplitViewController` in the current window.

Below codes was tested on XCode 13.2 and macOS 12.1.

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Replace with your sidebar view")
       .onAppear {
           guard let nsSplitView = findNSSplitVIew(view: NSApp.windows.first?.contentView), let controller = nsSplitView.delegate as? NSSplitViewController else {
                    return
           }
           controller.splitViewItems.first?.canCollapse = false
                // set the width of your side bar here.
           controller.splitViewItems.first?.minimumThickness = 150
           controller.splitViewItems.first?.maximumThickness = 150
       }
}

private func findNSSplitVIew(view: NSView?) -> NSSplitView? {
        var queue = [NSView]()
        if let root = view {
            queue.append(root)
        }
        while !queue.isEmpty {
            let current = queue.removeFirst()
            if current is NSSplitView {
                return current as? NSSplitView
            }
            for subview in current.subviews {
                queue.append(subview)
            }
        }
        return nil
}
```

Comment: This works brilliantly! I had to wrap the code in the `onAppear` block into  `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {}` though as `findNSSplitVIew` returned `nil` if called too early.

Comment: With the delay it also worked for me, but, it would work only one time. If I tried to drag it for a second time, it would collapse. The hacky solution I found was to add the findNSSplitVIew both onAppear and onHover. (not proud of that)

Answer (score 0):

While the method that Oskar used with the Introspect library no longer works, I did find another way of preventing the sidebar from collapsing using Introspect. First, you need to make an extension on View:

```
extension View {
    public func introspectSplitView(customize: @escaping (NSSplitView) -> ()) -> some View {
        return inject(AppKitIntrospectionView(
            selector: { introspectionView in
                guard let viewHost = Introspect.findViewHost(from: introspectionView) else {
                    return nil
                }
                return Introspect.findAncestorOrAncestorChild(ofType: NSSplitView.self, from: viewHost)
            },
            customize: customize
        ))
    }
}
```

Then do the following:

```
NavigationView {
     SidebarView()
         .introspectSplitView { controller in
                    (controller.delegate as? NSSplitViewController)?.splitViewItems.first?.canCollapse = false
                    
         }
            
     Text("Main View")
                
}
```

This being said, we don't know how long this will actually work for. Apple could change how NavigationView works and this method may stop working in the future.

Comment: This worked for me only if I added "controller.splitViewItems.first?.minimumThickness = 150 controller.splitViewItems.first?.maximumThickness = 150". But, it worked only the first time I tried to collapse the view. The same issue I faced with Jiakang's answer.